# meta_compare not comparing whole integer

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I have submitted an integer data via a form to my custom search page. I can get values properly if the input is single char (e.g. 1 ) but if the input is multi char (e.g. 100) it still compares against "1".

IF the user input is **1** I get all the posts with custom field value **More than 1**.
but If the input is **100** the result is same.

*Why is this happening??*

Here is my code::

```
$i_rate = $_GET["interest_rate"];

                $bc_args = array(

                    'post_type' => 'data',
                    'data-category'=>'insurance-rate',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'meta_key' => 'interest_rate',
                    'meta_value' =>$i_rate,
                    'meta_compare' => '>=',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

                );

                 $sortedPosts = new WP_Query($bc_args);
```

Comment: Should not 'meta_value' =>$i_rate, be 'meta_value_num' =>$i_rate,

Comment: @magenta I tried that too...but it doesn't work that way

Comment: Was going to suggest casting to INT on your value, but looks like the marked answer has you covered.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
$bc_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'data',
    'data-category'  =>'insurance-rate',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'interest_rate',
            'value'   => (int) $i_rate,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
    )
);

$sortedPosts = new WP_Query( $bc_args );
```

where we use the *numeric* `type`.

You should also consider using [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) instead of `$_GET`:

```
$i_rate = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'i_rate', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
```

or the native `add_query_var / get_query_var` way.

*Ps:* `data-category` is not a native parameter in the `WP_Query()` class.

Comment: Thank you so much.... it worked just I needed...I knew there was some type of casting problem just didn't know how to solve it. 

Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. You can always check the generated SQL with `echo $sortedPosts->request;` to make sure it's what you want.